# R: Conditionally replacing values based on column pre-fixes and suffixes

Tags: r, database, merge, data-manipulation

I have two data frames. Data frame A has many observations/rows, an ID for each observation, and many additional columns. For a subset of observations X, the values for a set of columns are missing/NA. Data frame B contains a subset of the observations in X (which can be matched across data frames using the ID) and variables with identical names as in data frame A, but containing values to replace the missing values in the set of columns with missing/NA.

My code below (using a join operation) merely adds columns rather than replacing missing values. For each of the additional variables (let's name them W) in B, the resulting table produces W.x and W.y.

```
library(dplyr)

foo <- data.frame(id = seq(1:6), x = c(NA, NA, NA, 1, 3, 8), z = seq_along(10:15))
bar <- data.frame(id = seq(1:2), x = c(10, 9))
dplyr::left_join(x = foo, y = bar, by = "id")
```

I am trying to replace the missing values in A using the values in B based on the ID, but do so in an efficient manner since I have many columns and many rows. My goal is this:

```
  id   x z 
1  1  10 1  
2  2   9 2  
3  3  NA 3  
4  4   1 4  
5  5   3 5  
6  6   8 6
```

One thought was to use ifelse() after joining, but typing out ifelse() functions for all of the variables is not feasible. Is there a way to do this simply without the database join or is there a way to apply a function across all columns ending in .x to replace the values in .x with the value in .y if the value in .x is missing?

Comment: This is the "update join" question, to which I've yet to see a really good answer. For the moment I've taken to `left_join(foo, bar, by = 'id') %>% mutate(x = coalesce(x.x, x.y)) %>% select(-contains('.'))`

Comment: It seems like there should be a way to avoid manually typing out mutate(foo = coalesce(foo.x, foo.y)) for each variable since I have thousands of them. I've been thinking through ways of using `apply` but am at a bit of a loss.

Comment: In `data.table` - `foo[bar,on=.(id),x := i.x]`

Comment: @user3614648 There's a programmatic approach operating on the column names, but frankly it's not simple or pretty.

Comment: `nm <- c("x"); foo[bar,on=.(id), (nm) := mget(paste0("i.",nm))]` or something similar if you just want to reference the names once. `nm` could also be defined using `names(foo)[c(-1,-length(foo))]` to avoid typing everything out.

Comment: @thelatemail I receive an error that on=.(id) is an unused argument when I implement either of the data table solutions.

Comment: @user3614648 - are you using a `data.table`? `library(data.table); setDT(foo); setDT(bar)` first?

Comment: @user3614648 ohh...wait! do you have multiple columns in `bar` as well ?

Comment: @RonakShah Yep! I think thelatemail got it right. I'm testing right now.

Comment: @thelatemail I'm new to data.table. It appears that on=.id subsets to rows where foo and bar have the same value of id. Then we update variable(s) nm to (named?) i.nm.  I'm not quite sure what is going on there, could you explain a little?

Comment: @user3614648 - that's pretty much it. It's a join on `id` and then updates the values from `bar` and writes them `:=` over the top of the values in `foo`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another attempt which should essentially only be one assignment operation. Using @alistaire's data again:

```
vars <- c("x","y")
foo[vars] <- Map(pmax, foo[vars], bar[match(foo$id, bar$id), vars], na.rm=TRUE)
foo

#  id  x y z
#1  1 10 1 1
#2  2  9 2 2
#3  3 NA 3 3
#4  4  1 4 4
#5  5  3 5 5
#6  6  8 6 6
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, this only works if the IDs for bar are in the first rows of foo, correct?

Comment: @user3614648 - nope, it will work in any order - `match` will take take of the ordering in the selection from `bar`. Try `foo <- foo[6:1,]` and run the code, it will just reverse as intended.

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT**

Updating the answer taking @alistaire 's example dataframe.

We can extend the same answer given below using `mapply` so that it can handle multiple columns for both `foo` and `bar`.

Finding out common columns between two dataframes and sorting them so they are in the same order.

```
vars <- sort(intersect(names(foo), names(bar))[-1])
foo[vars] <- mapply(function(x, y) {
             ind = is.na(x)
             replace(x, ind, y[match(foo$id[ind], bar$id)])
             }, foo[vars], bar[vars])

foo
#  id  x y z
#1  1 10 1 1
#2  2  9 2 2
#3  3 NA 3 3
#4  4  1 4 4
#5  5  3 5 5
#6  6  8 6 6
```

**Original Answer**

I think this does what you are looking for :

```
foo[-1] <- sapply(foo[-1], function(x) {
    ind = is.na(x)
    replace(x, ind, bar$x[match(foo$id[ind], bar$id)])
})


foo
#  id  x z
#1  1 10 1
#2  2  9 2
#3  3 NA 3
#4  4  1 4
#5  5  3 5
#6  6  8 6
```

For every column (except `id`) we find the missing value in `foo` and replace it with corresponding values from `bar`.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind verbose baseR approaches, then you can easily accomplish this using `merge()` and a careful subsetting of your data frame.

```
df <- merge(foo, bar, by="id", all.x=TRUE)
names(df) <- c("id", "x", "z", "y")
df$x[is.na(df$x)] <- df$y[is.na(df$x)]
df <- df[c("id", "x", "z")]

> df
  id  x z
1  1 10 1
2  2  9 2
3  3 NA 3
4  4  1 4
5  5  3 5
6  6  8 6
```

Comment: If you can think of a way to do this across thousands of columns without typing $x, I'm happy to accept as an answer. Perhaps this can be done by defining a function that does the above but can than be sapply()'d?

Comment: There is a potentially bigger problem with my solution, namely that the merge can change column names.  My guess is that you'd need at least some manual renaming with my solution.  Someone like @akrun will give you a better answer.

Comment: The merge() portion is mostly extraneous. I can still use dplyr::left_join() and then proceed with df$x.x[is.na(df$x.x) <- df$x.y[is.na(df$x.y)], then  select(-contains('.y')) (under the presumption no variable has .y otherwise). But the subsetting is what is a pain.

Comment: Maybe you should update your question and let us know what the actual problem looks like.  In this case, a minimal example/solution doesn't seem to be cutting it.

Comment: The data are identical except there are many more variables like X and Z in the data frame.

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate `dplyr::coalesce` over the intersect of non-grouping columns. It's not elegant, but it should scale reasonably well:

```r
library(tidyverse)

foo <- data.frame(id = seq(1:6), 
                  x = c(NA, NA, NA, 1, 3, 8), 
                  y = 1:6,    # add extra shared variable
                  z = seq_along(10:15))
bar <- data.frame(id = seq(1:2), 
                  y = c(1L, NA),
                  x = c(10, 9))

# names of non-grouping variables in both
vars <- intersect(names(foo), names(bar))[-1]

foobar <- left_join(foo, bar, by = 'id')

foobar <- vars %>% 
    map(paste0, c('.x', '.y')) %>%    # make list of columns to coalesce
    map(~foobar[.x]) %>%    # for each set, subset foobar to a two-column data.frame 
    invoke_map(.f = coalesce) %>%    # ...and coalesce it into a vector
    set_names(vars) %>%   # add names to list elements
    bind_cols(foobar) %>%   # bind into data.frame and cbind to foobar
    select(union(names(foo), names(bar)))    # drop duplicated columns

foobar
#> # A tibble: 6 x 4
#>      id     x     y     z
#>   <int> <dbl> <int> <int>
#> 1     1    10     1     1
#> 2     2     9     2     2
#> 3     3    NA     3     3
#> 4     4     1     4     4
#> 5     5     3     5     5
#> 6     6     8     6     6
```